# Looking for a web based, client side form editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, webforms, client-side

I'm looking for a javascript library (could be based on jQuery) that will implement a client side Form Editor.

The perfect example is something like offered by http://wufoo.com/
You should play with their free version to get the feeling of what I'm trying to find.

Also see [this example](http://mikenovember.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/04/form-builder.html) someone made with jQuery. it is very basic, but a step in the right direction.

Do you know of any jQuery plugin or library that will give me the full functionality of form editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the awesome ExtJS framework to build such kind of application. Here's an example of what you can do.

[ext/formbuilder](http://tof2k.com/ext/formbuilder/)

Add a form panel, then drop a textbox and so on...dead simple. Ext JS 2.2 and 3.0 (not yet ready) are LGPL and GPL licensed, you have also commercial subscriptions available, I think it worth to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [jQuery Form Builder](http://experiments.botsko.net/tests/formbuilder/) plug-in from [Botsko](http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/jquery-form-builder-plugin/)

Comment: This is nice and sleek. I haven't seen this one before. But I am looking for something that is more WYSIWYG. In this one you can't see how the form itself looks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and wrote one. Github link: [SpiffForm](https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffForm).